# How to mock Object Params in Java

Tags: java, mockito

```
public class A {

    public ResultSet executeCql(String cql, boolean cachePrepared, ConsistencyLevel consistencyLevel, Object... values)
        {
            //...
        }

     //...
}
```

I have mocked the class A. And I have tried to mock method its not working.

```
when(a.executeCql(anyString(), anyBoolean(), any(), any(Object[].class))).thenReturn(resultSet);
```

Help me on this.

I have tried this also.

```
when(cassandraHelper.executeCql(any(), anyBoolean(), any(ConsistencyLevel.class), Matchers.<Object>anyVararg())).thenReturn(resultSet);
```

Still this method returns `null` instead of mocked `ResultSet`.

Comment: What does "not working" mean in more detail?

Comment: Are you sure `a` is an instance of a Mock? For example, via `@InitMocks`.

Comment: for mock i will use easy mock objects.

**Maven**

    `<dependency>
       <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
       <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
       <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>`

**Test class**

        `private A a;
    
        @Before
        public void setUp() throws IOException {
            a = EasyMock.createNiceMock(A.class);
         expect(a.executeCql(anyString(), anyBoolean(), any(), any(Object[].class)))).andReturn(resultSet);
         replay(a);
        }`
    
     
I think it will helps you !!